# Bibliotecas do Hibernate com especificação JPA

Tags: hibernate, query, jpa-2.0

estou usando JPA e Hibernate e encontrando dificuldades quanto a erros de querys. Gostaria de saber se existe uma biblioteca específica para JPQL?
e quais as necessárias para para projetos som esse perfil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### (JPQL) Java Persistence Query Language

É uma linguagem de consulta orientada a objeto independente de plataforma definida como parte da especificação Java Persistence API (JPA).

Como especificação, não temos que trazer uma lib especifica, já está na spec.

### Querydsl JPA

É um framework que permite a construção de queries type-safe SQL para vários backends incluindo JPA, MongoDB e SQL em Java.

Em vez de escrever consultas como cadeias inline ou exteriorizar-los em arquivos XML que são construídos através de uma API fluente.

**Exemplo com QueryDSL**

```
QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
Customer bob = query.from(customer)
  .where(customer.firstName.eq("Bob"))
  .uniqueResult(customer);
```

É simples assim, e essa pode ser uma boa opção para você fazer suas queries em JPA. Segue o link do site dele:

[Site](http://www.querydsl.com/)

Comment: Brother, não estou interessado em uma nova sintaxe de query.
gostaria de saber se nas bibliotecas do provedor hibernate teria alguma  alguma necessária ao suporte à JPQL.

Comment: Como especificação, não temos que trazer uma lib especifica, já está na spec.